# How to remove an element attribute with JavascriptExecutor and Selenium WD?

Tags: java, selenium, classcastexception

I have the below code to set up an auto bid on an auction site.
I have gotten stuck as the confirm button is disabled until the user types keypresses into the text field.
I can populate the field using `selenium.type` however this does not remove the disabled attribute from the button.

I was hoping there might be a way of removing the attribute once the `.type` command has finished.

I have searched many pages to find the answer and I have found that it might be possible but for the life of me I cannot get it to work.

Could somebody please help with what I am doing wrong here:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;


public class Bidder_Home_004 {
    private Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "URL");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testBidder_Home_004() throws Exception {

    //      Login   
        selenium.open("/bidderlogin");
        selenium.select("id=ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlBidder", "label=A H Biler");
        selenium.click("id=ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=hrefCurrent");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");

        Thread.sleep(3000);
    //      End Login           

    //      Navigate to Home page           
        selenium.click("//*[@id='hrefCurrent']");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    //      End Navigate to Home page

    //      Find Active Tab
        String linkHome = selenium.getText("//li[@class='active']");

        assertEquals("Igangværende", linkHome);
    //       End Find Active Tab

    //      Get Auction ID
        selenium.click("//*[@id='spanWait']");
        Thread.sleep(3000);         
        String linkAuctionlist = selenium.getValue("//*[starts-with(@id, 'liAuction')]/@id");           
        linkAuctionlist = linkAuctionlist.replace("liAuction", "");         
    //      End Get Auction ID

        // Get Vehicle ID           
        String carsinAuction = selenium.getValue("//*[1][contains(@id,'btnBidUp')]/@id");
        carsinAuction = carsinAuction.replace("btnBidUp","");
        // End Get Vehicle ID

    //Find Original Vehicle Value
        String OrgVal1 = selenium.getText("//*[@id='bidvalue_"+carsinAuction+"']");
        OrgVal1 = OrgVal1.replace("kr. ", "");
        OrgVal1 = OrgVal1.replace(".", "");
        int OrgVal2 = Integer.parseInt(OrgVal1);            
        int nextBid = (OrgVal2 + 1500);         
    // End Find Original Vehicle Value

    // Click AutoBid button         
        selenium.click("//*[@id='btnProxy"+carsinAuction+"']");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        selenium.type("//*[@id='txtProxyBid']", ""+nextBid+"");

    ((JavascriptExecutor)selenium).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled','disabled')");

        selenium.click("//*[@id='btnSubmit']");

        Thread.sleep(2000);
    // End Click AutoBid button

    // Find New Vehicle Value
        String NewVal1 = selenium.getText("//*[@id='bidvalue_"+carsinAuction+"']");
        NewVal1 = NewVal1.replace("kr. ", "");
        NewVal1 = NewVal1.replace(".", "");
        int NewVal2 = Integer.parseInt(NewVal1);

    // End Find New Vehicle Value   
        String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy'Autobid.txt'").format(new Date());
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
                writer.println(NewVal2);
                writer.close();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }

}
```

As you can see in the "*Click Autobid Button*" section I have a line that includes `JavascriptExecutor` - this is a line that I have found on other forums and within stackoverflow however I have not yet gotten it to work.

When I execute I have the ***following error***:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor

***How to solve this error issue?***

Comment: You are mixing selenium 1 & 2 (Webdriver) versions. Decide which one you want to use (most of the people will prefer Webdriver).

Comment: Sorry for my in=gnorance but can you please highlight where I have mixed these?

Comment: I am new to automation and thought everything was fine, all of the code works correctly apart from the remove 'disabled' part

Comment: @TonyII Is your question solved, now?

Comment: Hi @nazar_art no my question is not yet solved, I have taken on board that I may have mixed 2 versions, though I am not sure how, can only think that exporting the code from recording and then manually editing may have been my mistake.
I am currently working on starting the script from scratch without recording to see if I can get it to work. Any more help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please don't code dump. Read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

For Selenium Webdriver:
Please remove following lines from your code in import section:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
```

it causes to some conflicts

Comment: Code wont compile if imports are removed. OP is mixing selenium 1 and webdriver so he need to fix it.

Comment: Correct code does not compile without those imports, still unsure where I have mixed the versions though

Answer (score 0):

The reason is at your wrapper class `DefaultSelenium`.

for casting to `JavascriptExecutor` it should be distinct instance of  selenium's `Driver` instance.

And it should looks as follows:

> ((JavascriptExecutor) DefaultSelenium.getDriverInstance()).executeScript()

For solving casting to `JavascriptExecutor` you should return explisit instance of driver (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE... drivers).

And this method should has signature like following:

```
class DefaultSelenium {
   // all class stuff here
   public static RemoteWebDriver getDriverInstance() {
       return currentDriverInstance;
   }
```

After you will have correct instance of Selenium `RemoteWebDriver` you able to cast it to `JavascriptExecutor` and execute ***JS script***.

***BTW:***

Using `Thread.sleep()` is very bad style.

Much better is to use ***explicit waits*** - [Explicit and Implicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)